# C/C++ Header file documentation

Tags: c++, c, documentation, javadoc

What do you think is best practice when creating public header files in C++?

1. Should header files contain no, brief or massive documentation? I've seen everything from almost no documentation (relying on some external documentation) to large specifications of invariants, valid parameters, return values etc. I'm not sure exactly what I prefer, large documentation is nice since you've always access to it from your editor, on the other hand a header file with very brief documentation can often show a complete interface on one or two pages of text giving a much better overview of what's possible to do with a class.
2. Let's say I go with something like brief or massive documentation. I want something similar to javadoc where I document return values, parameters etc. What's the best convention for that in c++? As far as I can remember doxygen does good stuff with java doc-style documentation, but are there any other conventions and tools for this I should be aware of before going for javadoc style documentation?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Usually I put documentation for the interface (parameters, return value, *what* the function does) in the interface file (.h), and the documentation for the implementation (*how* the function does) in the implementation file (.c, .cpp, .m).

I write an overview of the class just before its declaration, so the reader has immediate basic information.

The tool I use is Doxygen.

Answer (score 8):

1. I would definetely have some documentation in the header files themselves. It greatly improves debugging to have the information next to the code, and not in separate documents. As a rule of thumb, I would document the API (return values, argument, state changes, etc) next to the code, and high-level architectural overviews in separate documents (to give a broader view of how everything is put together; it's hard to place this together with the code, since it usually references several classes at once).
2. Doxygen is fine from my experience.

Answer (score 4):

I believe Doxygen is the most common platform for generating documentation, and as far as I know, it's more or less able to cover JavaDoc-notation (not limited to of course). I've used doxygen for C, with OK results, I do think it's more suitable for C++ though. You might want to look into robodoc as well, although I think Occam's Razor will tell you to rather go for Doxygen.

Regarding how much documentation, I've never been a documentation-fan myself, but whether I like it or not, having more documentation always beats having no documentation. I'd put the API-documentation in the header file, and the implementation documentation in the implementation (stands to reason, doesn't it?). :) That way, IDEs have the chance to pick it up and show it during autocompletion (Eclipse does this for JavaDocs, for example, perhaps also for doxygen?), which shouldn't be underestimated. JavaDoc has this additional quirk that it uses the first sentence (i.e. up to the first full stop) as a brief description, don't know if Doxygen does this though, but if so, it should be taken into consideration when writing the documentation.

Having a lot of documentation runs the risk of being out of date, however, keeping the documentation close to the code will give people a chance to keep it up to date, so you should definately keep it in the source/header files. What shouldn't be forgotten though is the production of documentation. Yes, some people will use the documentation directly (through the IDE or whatever, or just reading the header file), but some people prefer other ways, so you should probably consider putting your (regularly updated) API documentation online, all nice and browsable, as well as perhaps producing man-files if you're targeting *nix-based developers.

That's my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

Put enough into the code that it can stand alone. Nearly every project I've been in where the documentation was separate, it got out of date or wasn't done, partly that if it's a separate document it becomes a separate task, partly as management didn't allow for it as a task in budgetting. Documenting inline as part of the flow works much better in my experience.

Write the documentation in a form which most editors recognise is a block; for C++ this seems to be /* rather than //. That way you can fold it and just see the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would be interested in [gtk-doc](http://www.gtk.org/gtk-doc/). It can be "a bit awkward to setup and use" but you can get a nice API documentation from source code, looking like this:

[String Utility Functions](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html)