# doxygen: html formatting of declaration vs definition in C

Tags: c, doxygen

question is related to [Using Doxygen with C, do you comment the function prototype or the definition? Or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272039/using-doxygen-with-c-do-you-comment-the-function-prototype-or-the-definition-o) .

doxygen formatting makes the declaration and its comments from my .h file appear first, followed by the definition and its comments from my .c file.  good.

alas, is there some parameter like \param[in] or \return[in] that I can use just before the .c definition for the html output to indicate visually "now I am describing implementation"?  It could put a boldface on the left, or even change the color to set it off visually.  The obvious \implements tag does not do this.

I looked at the generated doxygen html code, and there is no obvious css class to change.  so I presumably should use a tag from http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html .  what do others use?

Answer (score 0):

One option, which is not ideal but does have the merit of simplicity, is to use the `\note` command.

Prefixing the paragraphs describing the implementation with `\note` will result in them showing in the output with a green'y-yellow sidebar.  You could change the color in the CSS. Subsequent `\note` paragraphs will remain as separate paragraphs but have a single heading and sidebar.

The downside is that the section is headed **Note:**.  This may or may not be acceptable for your needs.

You *could* use `\xrefitem` instead, which would allow you to change the text to **Implementation:**, but it, quite reasonably, also generates an entry on a separate cross-reference page - which is probably not desirable.  There may be a way of disabling the cross-indexing, but there's nothing in the [manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem) about it.

I assume you are generating a document that is for internal use only; some form of Technical Manual perhaps?  In which case, the 'Note' option may be the quickest and simplest solution.

**Edit**: I've just found the `\remark` command.  Essentially equivalent to `\note` without a sidebar, but the associated heading **Remarks** may suit your application better.  Chances are you can add the sidebar in the CSS.